# No puedo asignar el primer carácter de un string a una variable

Tags: python, string, input, indices

Me sale un error que dice que el string está fuera del rango pero es el primer índice.

```
>>> num=input("ingrese un número de tres dígitos")
ingrese un número de tres dígitos
>>> num1=int(num[0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    num1=int(num[0])
IndexError: string index out of range
>>>
```

Comment: Hola Fabrico, el código es correcto, el problema es que **no has ingresado absolutamente nada en el input** aparte del carácter de nueva línea/retorno de carro, por lo que `input` retorna una cadena vacía, es decir `num1=int(num[0])` es `num1=int(''[0])`.

Comment: Hola intenté la solución y no funcionó, me salió el mismo error
>>> num=input("ingrese un número de tres dígitos")
ingrese un número de tres dígitos
>>> num1=int(''[0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    num1=int(''[0])
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: No es una solución, es solo la explicación del problema, lo que quiero decir es que cuando te imprime `ingrese un número de tres dígitos` no puedes pulsar la tecla `Enter` sin más o ingresarás una cadena vacía, si en vez de eso ingresas algo como `123` y a continuación pulsas `Enter` el código funcionará como se espera...

Comment: Y cuándo quiero que el programa pida al usuario ingresar un número de 3 dígitos cualesquiera.¿Cuál sería la sintaxis?

Comment: La que usas..., repito, el código es correcto, el problema es que no ingresas nada como entrada, el input hace eso exactamente ¿Dónde ejecutas ese código?

Comment: Es en python...

Comment: Ya, pero me refería a si lo hacías en un IDE o en el intérprete interactivo directamente en la consola o el el IDLE (más que nada por si  el IDE ignora la entrada por stdin aal ejecutar el código o algo así). Aquí tienes un ejemplo del código para probarlo online: https://repl.it/repls/TimelyExternalInfo. Repito, ingresa tres números cuando pide que se ingresen, no hay más. Se puede validar la entrada para que siga pidiendo el número si el usuario no ingresa nada o no es un número o tiene menos de tres digitos, pero eso es otro tema.

Answer (score 0):

El error te salta porque no estas ingresando ningun valor a tu variable"num"
Cuando tu ejecutes tu codigo en algun compilador le pedira al usuario ingresar el valor
Te recomiendo usar Spyder y cuando lo hayas instalado ejecutalo y tu programa correra
otra opcion es utilizar un compilador online como este: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_compiler
copia tu codigo y dale a click a run(puedes borrar el codigo que esta por defecto) y entonces ya te dejara ingresar el numero por teclado. Espero haberte ayudado